# replace null values in sql pivot

Tags: sql-server, null, pivot

I have the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value)
  FOR [Period] IN ([06/1/2007],[07/1/2007])
)
AS p
```

Some of the rows returned are null but i want to replace them with 0.

I've tried `SUM(ISNULL(Value,0)) as Val` but it's not working. ( it's saying incorrect syntax)

Comment: Is that *exactly* what you tried? It's missing a `)`. In fact, your original query seems to have an extra `)`.

Comment: It usually helps when "it's not working" is explained in useful terms.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ohh, I was using `ISNULL` in the wrong place.

the query should look like this:

```
SELECT ID,ISNULL([06/1/2007],0), ISNULL([07/1/2007],0)
FROM Table1
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value)
  FOR [Period] IN ([06/1/2007],[07/1/2007])
)
AS p
```

Comment: I was trying to put the isnull in the pivot as well.  When I saw your answer, I felt really bad.