# want to change null values to zero

Tags: sql-server, pivot

i want to avoid `null` values and get zero when no monthly sales in each month

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 (
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, doa) [Month], sum(1) [Sales Count]
    From crime
    GROUP BY YEAR(doa),DATENAME(MONTH, doa)
 ) AS MontlySalesData 
 PIVOT
 ( 
   sum([Sales Count])  FOR Month 
   IN 
   (
     [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],
     [August],[September],[October],[November],[December]
    )
  ) AS MNamePivot
```

Comment: You can use the `ISNULL()` function

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT *` in the final select, you'll need to replace the `null` with zero for each column - `select isnull(january, 0) as january...`

Comment: You asked this exact question earlier. What was wrong with the answers ?

Comment: [replace null values in sql pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297132/replace-null-values-in-sql-pivot);  or [How to replace (null) values with 0 output in PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322342/how-to-replace-null-values-with-0-output-in-pivot)

Comment: the query was wrong that i posted.but iwas was unable to edit it for 90mintes

Comment: thank u every one for helping me

Answer (score -3, accepted):

mb you need to use *ifnull()*?
http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/system/ifnull.html